# Drupal 7: not showing uploaded images

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I use **Drupal 7** , and I create new **content type** and I add new **image field**  to upload an image to content, the image was uploaded successful but its not displayed when I view my content , but its displayed when I edit the content.

I changed the permission for the file sites/default/files to 777.

what I miss please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images are successfully uploaded on server and you see it in edit mode, it is definitely not a problem related to permissions.

Verify if your image field is shown in the `Default` display mode (or any other desired display mode, i.e. `Teaser`). It is under `Structure > Content Types > [Your Content Type] > Manage Display`.

Your image field should be listed in the upper part of the table, not in the part where you have `hidden` written.